# Custom Logs in Apache

Tags: apache, logging

I am trying to add up a filter to the apache logs and create a new file. My httpd-vhosts file looks something like this-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.com
    ServerAlias local.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/preetika.shukla/apps/devices"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
    CustomLog "|/usr/bin/grep \’test\'>>/var/log/apache2/test_access" common
    ServerAdmin preetika.shukla@olacabs.com
    <Directory "/Users/preetika.shukla/apps/devices">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

in short, I want `test_Access log file` to contain only those logs pertaining to where test keyword. How ever this doesn't seem to work, any suggestions as to how to get through this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a perl script to fetch regex using grep command.

Comment: doesn't adding grep in custom log do the same ?

Comment: the perl script will parse the original apache log file and filter the lines with the keyword 'test' and post output to the custom log file

Comment: @kd0807 -  I am facing the same problem, but I don't have any idea of perl script, can you write the perl script for the same, PLEASE :)

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved using the following:

1. Write a shell script(test.sh) which has the required functionality, make sure this script keeps on running. If this exits after a certain period of time, server throws an error:
   `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/access_log | /usr/bin/grep --line-buffered test >> /var/log/apache2/test_access` (here i am trying to grep for test in access_log)
2. Append the vhosts or httpd.conf file-
   CustomLog "|$/etc/apache2/extra/test.sh" common //- test.sh
3. restart the server and monitor the logs. :)